# Meta/Main rep not being linked up?

Tags: support, reputation

Why isn't the reputation between meta/the main site being linked up?

> [image: meta rep]
>
> [image: main site rep]

Comment: I'm was gonna give this issue at least a day to warm up, but I don't have any rep from my posts so far and I'm not worried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Caching. Meta rep always takes a while to refresh (on all sites). If it still hasn't caught up in an hour or two, you may begin to get worried.

Comment: Didn't think they cached between the two. Will be on the lookout; thanks! :)